# Carry objreader file being read over from form to form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, readline, multiple-forms

Okay so I'm making a multiple-choice quiz game for an assignment and I have a form for the list of categories and the actual questions. Because I'm quite new at coding and don't really have a whole lot of time to totally restructure my code in a way that I probably wouldn't understand, instead of adding all the buttons to one buttons "Handles" I just made a sub for each click event. 
This is an example of one of these subs:

```
    Public Sub btnMusic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMusic.Click
    Questions.Show()
    Me.Close()
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("Music.txt")
End Sub
```

My text is read by the following structure:

```
    Structure QuizQ
    Dim Q As String
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String
    Dim C As String
    Dim D As String
    Dim Correct As String
End Structure
```

I then try to read the lines according to the structure with:

```
            Dim I As Integer
        For I = 0 To 5
            MyQ(I).Q = objReader.ReadLine
            MyQ(I).A = objReader.ReadLine
            MyQ(I).B = objReader.ReadLine
            MyQ(I).C = objReader.ReadLine
            MyQ(I).D = objReader.ReadLine
            MyQ(I).Correct = objReader.ReadLine
        Next I
```

and then set the text for all of the buttons to the possible answers like so:

```
    lblQuestion.Text = MyQ(qNum).Q
    btnA.Text = MyQ(qNum).A
    btnB.Text = MyQ(qNum).B
    btnC.Text = MyQ(qNum).C
    BtnD.Text = MyQ(qNum).D
```

But at this point the text isn't displayed on the buttons or where the question should be. I really have no idea what I could do from this point so any help really would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where does the third and forth code block reside? Inside the form? You need to you show the full method body.